# Bloodhound Cypher: Negate CanRDP

Tags: cypher

To get all users who can RDP, I use the following

```
MATCH p=()-[r:CanRDP]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

My question is how would I negate this to get a list of users who can not RDP and combine it to the following query to bring users who can not RDP

```
{
    "name": "Shortest Paths to Domain Admins from Kerberoastable Users",
    "queryList": [
        {
            "final": false,
            "title": "Select a Domain Admin group...",
            "query": "MATCH (n:Group) WHERE n.objectsid =~ {name} RETURN n.name ORDER BY n.name DESC",
                "props": {"name": "(?i)S-1-5-.*-512"}
        },
        {
            "final": true,
            "query":"MATCH (n:User),(m:Group {name:{result}}),p=shortestPath((n)-[r:{}*1..]->(m)) WHERE n.hasspn=true RETURN p",
            "allowCollapse": true,
            "endNode": "{}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like `MATCH (u :User) WHERE NOT (u)-[:CanRDP]->() RETURN u`?

Comment: Might be helpful ,,,   https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#filter-on-patterns-using-not